# Difference between Decryption-failure and Plaintext-checking oracles

Tags: public-key, lattice-crypto, side-channel-attack, kem, decryption-oracle

I am reading [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/563.pdf), which in the introduction, tells about two main types of key recovery SCAs :

- Reaction_type SCAs, which uses a decryption failure oracle
- Message-recovery-type SCAs, which uses a plaintext-checking oracle

I don't understand the difference between these two oracles. In [this presentation](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/documents/round-3/seminars/mar-2021-ravi-sujoy-presentation.pdf), the authors categorize three different oracles, including these two.

My understanding is that a plaintext-checking oracle takes a ciphertext $c$ and a plaintext $m$ and returns 1 if the decryption of $c$ gives $m$, and 0 otherwise.

Regarding decryption failure oracle, it returns 0 if the decryption has failed, 1 otherwise. I don't understand if this oracle only takes a ciphertext $c$ or also a plaintext $m$. This is really unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood in the presentation, there are two ways to compromise the mentioned PQ Algorithms. Both use maliciously crafted Cipher Texts but either recover Secret Keys or the Plain Text

Comment: Did you mean *neither* (attack) recovers secret keys or the plaintext?